# A pattern to implement a secure client side session storage (web site)

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

I need to store a state of a paging component between page visits (specifically I need to save currently viewed page, number of items to show per page, and filter/search criteria text).

At first I thought about using localStorage to create a client-side-local-session. But this does not work in IE8, so I fall back to using session cookies when in IE8. But filter/search criteria is sensitive data so session cookies are not acceptable.

Now I am thinking about using server side session storage, but I would like to make the implementation transparent. The idea is to create a global javascript object (or jQuery plugin) called "local session". Local session implementation will send its content with every request (using jQuery AJAX beforeSend callback). So every request will send a fresh state of the clients "local session".

Server than will include all local session data with each freshly rendered page (i.e. only for non-AJAX responses).

I am using ASP.NET MVC and it would be easy to create a global filter that will be collecting this "local session" data and storing it in the server side session.

Two questions:

1. is storing sensitive data in javascript object any more secure than storing this data in  session cookie?
2. would it be a good idea to send local session content as a header (I can do some optimization and only send it when it actually changes, or even only send the changes).
3. any other suggestions for implementing this requirement?

Note: using history API won't work in IE8, it also not quite what I need (page state should be persisted even if I get back to the page by following a link, not by clicking BACK button).

**Note:** It would be nice if the solution would work when cookies are disabled, but this is not a strict requirement though.

Comment: Supporting IE8 kills me, I feel your pain

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the integrity and confidentiality of what's sent to the browser to be stored in a cookie you could sign and encrypt the value using server-side secret key(s) like in Ruby on Rails version 4.

However, keep in mind that the cookie would be subject to replay attacks and there is a size limit.